# Validation is only applied to the first item of an array

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

Given this model code

```cs
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

the following view code works

```cs
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
```

Whenever I leave the `Name` field empty, the `TextBox` is highlighted in red, and a `"The Name field is required."` error message appears, which is good.

---

However, my model also contains an `Option[] Options` which also need to be validated.

Given this model code

```cs
private const string orderNoDisplayName = "Order number";
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"\d+",
              ErrorMessage = "The " + orderNoDisplayName  + " field must be numeric.")]
[Display(Name = orderNoDisplayName )]
public string OrderNo { get; set; }
```

the following view code doesn't quite work as expected

```cs
@foreach (var option in Option.GetDefaultOptions())
{
    <li>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => option.OrderNo, new { id = option.IdString })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => option.OrderNo,
                                       null, new { data_valmsg_for = option.IdString })
    </li>
}
```

The very first `option` works perfectly, but any subsequent `option` doesn't.

Below is the automatically generated code for 2 `option`s

```html
<ul>

    <li> <!-- automatically generated code for 'option_1' -->
        <input data-val="true" data-val-regex="The Order number field must be numeric."
data-val-regex-pattern="\d+" data-val-required="The Order number field is required."
id="option_1" name="OrderNo" type="text" value="0" class="input-validation-error">

        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="option_1"
data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </li>

    <li> <!-- automatically generated code for 'option_2' -->
        <input id="option_2" name="OrderNo" type="text" value="0"
class="input-validation-error">

        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="option_2"
data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </li>

</ul>
```

So obviously, MVC **did not** add any validation attributes to my second `option` or any subsequent `option`s at all.

Of course, I could hardcode the validations into a handwritten `<input>` tag, but I'd like to avoid doing so. What can I do to make the validation work for all `option`s, instead of only the first one?

Comment: what do the auto generated inputs look like?  It looks like from the code that all of your inputs are identical.  That would be the reason why only the first is validated

Comment: @MattBodily The auto-generated code is already included (it's the last code block), I just added comments to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is the for loop, as the model binder is not indexing the name field they're coming out identical and it looks like there is only one i.e. `name="OrderNo"`.

Try changing your loop to index it as follows:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Option.GetDefaultOptions().Count; i++)
{
    <li>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Option.GetDefaultOptions()[i].OrderNo, new { id = Option.GetDefaultOptions()[i].IdString })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Option.GetDefaultOptions()[i].OrderNo,
                                       null, new { data_valmsg_for = Option.GetDefaultOptions()[i].OrderNo.IdString })
    </li>
}
```

You should then see that they're written out as follows:

```
 name="[0].OrderNo"
 name="[1].OrderNo"
```

Comment: Awesome, it really works. Didn't know the indexer was so significant.

Comment: @Nolonar Excellent, I know it got me too. Once you know, you never forget. :)