# MVC 4 Group validation message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, partial-views

I want to group my ValidationMessageFor at the top of the page instead of after each edit/textbox.

Is it possible to do something like this or is there any other way to achieve my idea?

`@Html.Partial("_PartialView", MyModel)`

```
@model MyModel
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(item)
}
```

Instead of doing this:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Foo)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Bar)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.etc..
```

Comment: check this out...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529880/validation-is-only-applied-to-the-first-item-of-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think these two steps are enough

```
1. Remove the Html.ValidationMessageFor()
2. Add Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Your custom summary message") inside using(html.BeginForm()
```

Comment: Follow-up question: Is it possible to get those messages triggered by javascript? I found this one that worked on the Html.ValidationMessageFor() `$('input[data-val=true]').on('blur', function () { $(this).valid() ;});` (now it only makes the textboxes border red)

Comment: yup..you can try unobtrusive..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538082/asp-net-mvc-3-required-steps-for-unobtrusive-client-side-validation-of-dynamic

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be looking for

`@Html.ValidationSummary()`